# Optimizing a Minotaur PC

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats, class, character-levels

Was wondering if any one would be able to help flesh out my character and help me make him better.
At the moment we are in a 14 level campaign using complete and core books D&D 3.5 edition also including eberon campaign so for I have taken 1 level in barbarian and 5 in bear warrior which when coupled with the +6 HD and the 2 LA maxes me out for my levels. Could you help with good feats that may be of use. My core stats rolled where 18,13,18,14,15,07. Before any racial additions. Any help in right direction people could give would help I am aiming to be high damage and HP. The only feat I have taken so far is power attack but looking at greater powerful charge if I can any help in this will be great as it my first non caster class and not to sure what to use. My weapon of choice is also a great axe.

Comment: 6 RHD and LA +2 is prohibitively painful; the minotaur’s stats aren’t worth those by a long shot. Would it be possible to maybe use the half-minotaur stats (*Dragon* vol. 313) but call yourself a minotaur? It will **massively** improve the character.

Comment: Unfortunately not he wants us to only use core books and complete and eberon at most.

Answer (score 2):

Some things to consider for this character (borrowed partially from [A Systemless Guide to Practical Optimization](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?t=157266)):

> What do you plan on accomplishing with this character?

- From a mechanical standpoint, it seems you want to make a durable, melee bruiser.
- From a role-playing perspective, you should consider the implications of playing a 3-int, lowish charisma character that fights from instinct.  Do you *really* want to play a character this stupid?

I recommend you put one 18 in Strength, and assign the other 18 to either Wisdom 
or Constitution, depending on which Saving Throw you prioritize more.

Keep in mind that as a [Monstrous Humanoid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#monstrousHumanoidType) you are immune to Dominate Person, Charm Person, Hold Person and *any other effects that target the Humanoid type*.  I do not know your DM, but if he argues that humanoids and monstrous humanoids are one and the same, point him to the following pages of the SRD: [Monstrous Humanoid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#monstrousHumanoidType), [Humanoid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#humanoidType) and [Psionic Dominate;](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/psionic/powers/dominatePsionic.htm) the latter specifically calls out Monstrous Humanoids as different from Humanoids for the purposes of Dominate Person.

**Alternate Class Features:**
Complete Champion has several good level 1 ACFs for barbarians, all of which replace the Fast Movement Class Feature.  Two are notable for your character:

- Spiritual Totem: Bear Totem: This totem grants *[Improved Grab](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/specialAbilities.htm#improvedGrab)* as a class feature; having this outside of Brown Bear form may be useful.
- Spiritual Totem: Lion Totem: You or your DM may have heard of this online, so tread carefully here.  It allows you to full attack on a charge, which gives you the ability to deal much more damage than normal during, say, the surprise round in which you would normally only have a standard action.  You might prefer this over the Spirit Bear Totem, if you spend more time Raging than not.

**Grappling:**

As a large sized creature with a massive strength bonus, you have 12(BAB)+4(Size)+12(26 strength-10/2 to get a mod of 8).  That translates to a total +24 to grapple checks, before rage.  While raging you gain a utterly *ridiculous* bonus to strength (+16, so +8 more to your grapple) but **cannot wield your normal weapons while in bear form.**  Thus, you should always keep grappling in mind as an option, if not your primary mode of offense--you are nearly guaranteed to pin down any low strength humanoid opponent, for one.

**Feats:**

Extra Rage: This nifty little feat gives you two more Rages per day; **you need this feat for your Bear Warrior levels to be worth anything at all.**  I seriously recommend you rethink your choice of class, as currently you can only use your Bear Form **one time per day**.  In other words, all it gains you is scent (you already have this as a minotaur) and Rage abilities that you can very rarely use.  If you insist on going with Bear Warrior, you should probably just take this feat at every level past your first level of barbarian.
Other: Bear Warrior doesn't specify that the rage or frenzy needs to be from your class features.  Get a friendly caster to cast Rage on you, or pick up a constant item of it, and be a bear all day long.

**Other racial choices:**

I would almost seriously recommend that you instead change your race to the core Lycanthropic Badger (Natural) applied to whatever LA +0 race you like.  You would only have a level adjustment of 3+1rhd, and will rage for free whenever you take damage in Animal Form.  This both qualifies you for Bear Warrior without the Barbarian level, gives you more room for actual class features superior to the Minotaur race and allows you effective infinite uses of your Bear Warrior class features.  Despite the apparent penalties, the ability to use your Bear Warrior features and 4 more levels in actual classes are far superior to the benefits of being a Minotaur.  The badger form is also useful for utility purposes: it allows you to burrow, and has a 10 ft. movement speed.

Comment: Unfortunately am restricted to Minotaur but in our party we have a caster type who will be suplimenting my rages with the rage spell or a wand of similar nature. Thanks for the info on spirit totems I will suggest this to my DM and see if he will allow it but just wondering for example does spirit totem lions pounce make my character do his charge/Gore DMG then get his full round attacks ?

Comment: Yes, Pounce allows you to get a full attack along with whatever effects you get on a charge.  Keep in mind that the Spirit Lion Totem does not refer to any particular tribe or group, but rather a *personal* spiritual connection to Lions.  By the way, is the restriction on races due to a lack of books, or for a limit on power level?  (If there are any other PCs filling a similar fighter-type role, could you send me a link to their sheets? It would help to see the overall power level in your group)

Comment: Oh yes, another option, if you can talk your DM into letting you use Races of Stone: Take Improved Bull Rush (PHB) Rampaging Bull Rush (Races of Stone) and Knockback (Races of Stone).  Knockback lets you bull rush for free on a melee attack, and Rampaging Bull Rush lets you knock enemies prone if you successfully bull rush them while raging.